# Keyof not working in template literals due to Symbols

Tags: typescript

I would expect either of these types to work, but these both throw errors.

```
export type Object1<T extends { [k: string]: any }> = `${keyof T}`;
export type Object2<T extends Record<string, any>> = `${keyof T}`;
```

They both give this error

```
TS2322: Type 'key T' is not assignable to type 'string | number | bigint | boolean | null | undefined'. 
 Type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type 'string | number | bigint | boolean | null | undefined'.
```

I'm not understanding why `symbol | number` are appearing despite specifying that the keys are strings.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Apologies, it's fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the constraints don't restrict the keys to strings. They require that all string keys in `T` have a value of type `any`, but it is perfectly fine for `T` to have other keys as well.

For example, if you leave out the template literal type to get rid of the error, you can apply `Object1` to an object type with a string, a number, and a symbol key:

```
type Object1<T extends {[k: string]: any}> = keyof T

type Test1 = Object1<{s: 'str', 1: 'num', [Symbol.iterator]: 'sym'}>
// type Test1 = typeof Symbol.iterator | "s" | 1
```

And the same thing holds for `Object2`:

```
type Object2<T extends Record<string, any>> = keyof T

type Test2 = Object2<{s: 'str', 1: 'num', [Symbol.iterator]: 'sym'}>
// type Test1 = typeof Symbol.iterator | "s" | 1
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwgY2ARgDwBUoQB7AQB2AJgM5QDeA2gNYBcUZwATgJZEDmAuowIZEQAXwB8UALxRaEEAHsAZlCwAoZaEhKIzNBNiIU6DJTKMA5MxamANFDRmiAVwC21qNQDKIJ3FkAbAHRshCx8wLIsvFDmXqaiygD08VDJAHoA-Krq0PBIqABM2LgExORQAEoo4SQYFhycNgIgImKS0nKKKmrg0FhawHm6OQYFxmYWrnZRji42Hl4%20AUEQIWERYzFxiclQ6cpAA)

Comment: `"the constraints don't restrict the keys to strings"`

I think this is the part that is confusing me. It seems like setting `[k: string]` would restrict all keys to be strings, if not what is the point of even allowing syntax that implies constraints?

Comment: @JDFrancis Record constraints allow you to specify a value type for certain keys, which can be useful. However, since `T` *extends* the record it may still have other keys. This is the same for any assignment: if you have an object with a string key `const x = {x: 'str'}`, you can still assign this to a record of number keys `const r: Record<number, boolean> = x` (https://tsplay.dev/wQVqvN).

Comment: Hmm that makes sense. Is there any way to achieve the behavior I'm looking for then? As in a way to strongly type the keys of an object in such a way that `keyof` will only return string?

Comment: @JDFrancis I don't think so. You could restrict created objects with something like `type StrObj = {[k: string]: any, [k: number | symbol]: never}`, but it won't restrict the keys. There might be some trick I'm not aware of though, so you could try asking specifically this in another question.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @Oblosys offers a good explanation why `keyof` still produces all possible key types even though you specified a constraint. If I understand your question correctly, your goal is to get all the keys of a type inside a string literal (maybe for further string manipulation?)

Maybe this can help you:

```js
export type KeyLiterals<T extends {[k: string] : any}> = 
  `${keyof T extends string | number ? keyof T : never}`;

type Test = KeyLiterals<{a: string, b: string}> // 'a' | 'b'
```

We can check if `keyof` is of type `string` or `number` to make sure that no `symbols` remain in the union.

---

Now you can do any further string manipulation like adding a prefix.

```js
export type KeyLiterals2<T extends {[k: string] : any}> = 
  `prefix_${keyof T extends string | number ? keyof T : never}`;

type Test2 = KeyLiterals2<{a: string, b: string}> // 'prefix_a' | 'prefix_b'
```

Answer (score 0):

this is normal behavior, read this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48269)

Answer (score 0):

Create your own `KeyOf` type that gets rid of `symbol`:

```
type KeyOf<T> = Exclude<keyof T, symbol>
type KeyOfStr<T> = `${KeyOf<T>}` // No error
```